# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hamcrest.beans.SamePropertyValuesAs.isNotNull(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/hamcrest/Description;)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, rest-assured, hamcrest

I am facing this issue when I am trying to run the tests using intelliJ (Version 11.0.5) only.(macos). When i run tests using Gradle commands it works fine though.

I noticed I am able to run these test successfully with older gradle dependency for rest-assured library.
testCompile('io.rest-assured:rest-assured:3.x.x') how ever we have the current dependency as
 testCompile('io.rest-assured:rest-assured:4.1.0'). Just wondering what is the issue with running them only in intelliJ as they run fine with regular Gradle build.

Comment: Does it fail in [IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.4 release](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html)? If the issue persists, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: same issue here, tests work with Gradle but not from IntelliJ. Version 2020.2.1 in my case.

Comment: @Clawdidr please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the logs and a sample project to reproduce.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, I created the report: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-250818